# Is there a way to use Google Apps Script to open a document at the last edit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, triggers

I have a Google Doc that's getting kind of long. I use it to collect pretty much all my thoughts on different projects, so I'd like it to open back up wherever I left off (not necessarily at the end). - I need it readily accessible on whatever device I'm on, that's why it's a Doc and not a Word file, even though I know how to write the macro there. -

After some digging, it looks like there's an edit trigger for sheets but not for docs, so I've been trying to get a time-based trigger instead as a best approximation of the most recent edit. I wrote the following in the doc's Code.gs, but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
function onOpen() { 
  deleteTrigger();
  createTrigger();
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().setCursor(PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('lastOpen')); 
}

function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('savePlace')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(1)
      .create();
} 

function savePlace() {
  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('lastOpen', DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor());
}

function deleteTrigger() {

  // Loop over all triggers and delete them
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
  }
}
```

(Also, do I have to specify a script property for *lastOpen* in the dialog box? And what's the best value to put in there if so. [I'm really, really new to this])

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Just save your bookmark when you leave.  And the use gotoBookMark when you open up the document.

```
function saveBookMark() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var cursor=doc.getCursor();
  var bookmark=doc.addBookmark(cursor);
  var ps=PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  ps.setProperty('bookmarkid', bookmark.getId());
}

function gotoBookMark() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var bookmarkid=PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('bookmarkid');
  var pos=doc.getBookmark(bookmarkid).getPosition();
  doc.setCursor(pos);
}
```

This will remove all bookmarks:

```
function clearBookMarks() {
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var bkmarks=doc.getBookmarks().forEach(function(bm){bm.remove();})
}
```

Here's the menu:

```
function menu() {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('MyMenu')
  .addItem('Save BookMark', 'saveBookMark')
  .addItem('Goto Bookmark', 'gotoBookMark')
  .addItem('Remove All Bookmarks', 'clearBookMarks')
  .addToUi();  
}
```

[Class Bookmarks](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/bookmark)

I've never actually used this before but I imagine with a little extra effort one could post an excerpt from each bookmark and provide a checkbox to select them and then only delete the ones you don't want and also provide a button next to each one so you could return to that one whenever you wish.

This was the sample code that got me rolling:

```
// Insert a bookmark at the cursor position and log its ID.
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var cursor = doc.getCursor();
var bookmark = doc.addBookmark(cursor);
Logger.log(bookmark.getId());
```

After that you can use code completion to figure out what methods are available and then refer to the manual when necessary.  It's interest sometimes code completion is updated before the document and sometimes the documentation gets updated first so you sometimes have to willing to wing it on your a bit.

I used the Document Properties Service to save the last bookmark id and so when you open up the document it always goes to the last bookmark.

[PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Comment: I tried your code and did some more debugging on mine and they both seem to be returning null on getCursor. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you put it in a Google document?

Comment: I just opened a new document that someone sent me recently and I copied that code from my answer into the script editor.  Setup an onOpen() function and put menu() in it and ran it to create the menu and authorize the script and it works right out of the box. Try running the function indepently from the script editor and see if you find some problems

Comment: Both of the documents I've used it in are running V8