# Why am I getting a TypeError on one of two app scripts that are exactly the same?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps

I'm very new to coding and don't really know what I'm doing yet.

I'm trying to set up an AppScript in Google Docs to remove bookmarks from a doc all at once. I have to convert Google Docs from Word and often one document will have well over 300 bookmarks that need to be removed. I used a script I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62097972/is-there-a-way-to-use-google-apps-script-to-open-a-document-at-the-last-edit/62098262#62098262), written by user Cooper. It works just fine on my home computer and personal G Drive account (see image below).

[image: Image showing working script on my home computer and personal G Drive]

But when I use the exact same script on my work computer and work Google account I get a type error. What am I missing? I've been trying to figure it out for two hours already and I feel like I'm going crazy. Both scripts are literally exactly the same. Copied and pasted.

[image: Image showing same script not working on my work computer, plus the error message]

Comment: I have the exact function in  two different accounts one is old gmail account and one is a business account and both work.  I don't run remote with openById() the document has to be opened by a user.

Comment: What were the steps that you followed to open each of the scripts?

Answer (score 2):

- It looks like the first script is a [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) script and hence the active document returns the bound document.
- On the other hand, the second one is a [standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) script and hence there is no active (bound) document and this is why `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()` returns `null`.

The solution to the problem would be either to open the script from the document itself, or open the document by its id instead by using [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openbyidid):

```
// Open a document by ID.
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('DOCUMENT_ID_GOES_HERE');
```

or by using its url and [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openbyurlurl):

```
// Open a document by URL.
var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(
  'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_a1b2c3/edit');
```

Comment: In my case they are contained scripts that run from either a menu or sidebar or they're integrated into other function.  I like to write stories and the tools that I use just make findingstuff that I want to refer to a lot easier.